# Wordpress Website Logo not appearing on website header

Tags: wordpress

I have a website in wordpress but  my logo is not coming on my website header.Website URL is www.shemrocknajafgarh.com.
Please help me to resolve this issue as soon as possible .I am very thankfull to you.
Thanks

Comment: You need to have more information about the theme you are using. It can be an option that you must activate on your theme settings or your theme don't provide a region for the logo.

Answer (score 3):

**Try This css**

```
    header .navbar-brand{
        width:100%;
    }
    .navbar-brand > img{
         /*max-height: 56px;*/ //remove this max-height
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: -12px;
    }
```

Comment: I want to make my this website responsive please tell me any wordpress plugin or any code hint.

Comment: can you please accepts my answer????  used the boostrap class or foundation class so it make automatically responsive. there are no any plugin for responsive.

Comment: if you accepts this by green right sign then this answer will used for the other community.

Comment: Thank You for your advice i will try it soon.One Problem occurs in my website in portfolio page header not appearing I added an image slider in portfolio page.

Comment: please accepts my answer show it can help for other community for more helping.